# Clever way to clean dirty flag in c++

Tags: c++, design-patterns, software-design

I have this case where I am trying to expose a standard API for spatial search structures, where the input data for the various method of building the structure is the same, but the way the search structure is built is different.
I have setters for the data on the base class and a pure virtual Build() method that the derived classes need to implement to construct the search structure.
Below is sort of how my base class looks like

```
class SpatialSearch
{
public:
  void SetData(Data data_)
  {
    this->data = data_;
    this->dirty = true;
  }

  virtual void Build() = 0;

  int search(Vec3 point)
  { 
    if(dirty)
      Build();
    // Code to perform a search. I won't get into the 
    // nitty gritty of this, but this exists as a commom
    // implementation on the base class for all the spatial 
    // search structures.
  }

private : 
  Data data;
  bool dirty;
}
```

So if you notice, every call to search has a check for the `dirty` flag.
And if the data has been changed after the last time, I rebuild the structure.
However, the Build method is implemented on the derived class, and I need a way to enforce a means of setting this flag to `false` after the Build method has been execute, and not just leave a guideline for the person writing the derived class to have `dirty = false` in their 'Build' method.

In short, I need a way to make sure the user has set `dirty = false` after every execution of the `Build` method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A common way to do this is to have a vertical interface and a horizontal one (protected & public).

The "horizontal interface" is the one the users of the class see and the "vertical" one is the one that the derived class implementers override to add functionality.

```
class SpatialSearch
{
public:
  void SetData(Data data_)
  {
    this->data = data_;
    this->dirty = true;
  }

  void Build() // no longer virtual
  {
    internal_build(); 
    dirty = false;
  }

  int search(Vec3 point)
  { 
    if(dirty)
      internal_build();
    // Code to perform a search. I won't get into the 
    // nitty gritty of this, but this exists as a commom
    // implementation on the base class for all the spatial 
    // search structures.
  }

protected:
  virtual void internal_build() = 0; // implementers override this

private : 
  Data data;
  bool dirty;
}

class SpecialSpatialSearch
: public SpatialSearch
{
protected:
  void internal_build() override
  {
    // do the build without caring or knowing of the 
    // existence of the dirty flag
  }
};
```